# pROC package with pre-specified cutoff values with two decimals

Tags: r, roc, threshold, proc-r-package

In the `roc` function of `pROC` package I would like to print my specific cutoff values (`print.thres` parameter) with two decimal digits, because one cutoff is `0.05` and in the plot appears as `0.0` Any suggestion?

Comment: `print.thres.pattern="%.2f"` maybe?

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło why not write it as an answer?

Comment: @Calimo Because that's a guess. I didn't check if that works, just posted an idea.

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło it works, thank you. Sorry, kjetil b halvorsen, I didn't know it was off-topic here, I will be more careful next time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `print.thres.pattern` argument to the plot function:

```
myROCcurve <- roc(...)
plot(myROCcurve, print.thres = 0.05, print.thres.pattern="%.2f")
```